# Unable to view VM webserver on other PC on LAN

Tags: webserver, vmware-player

I have apache running on Ubuntu 12.04, running on VMware Player , on a Win 7 desktop, and I'm able to view my dev site fine on the Win 7 desktop.  The problem is that I can't view it on any other machines on my LAN.  This is particularly a problem because I need to view/test my site on my phone.

So how I can make my VM viewable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your VM must be set to use Bridged networking in your VMWare player software. This way your VM gets and IP address from the same network as other devices at your home.